# Cannot implement auto-advance fullpage slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

js slider
Forgive me as I'm new to coding.
Great plugin, but I can't get the auto advance code to work fully.
Here's the issue: when I implement the auto advance code it works. However when I click on a menu item above the slider (right before it loads another slide) the slider goes blank. This also happens if I go back to the slider and from another page (depending on the timing).

http://dev.believemedia.com

Comment: I'm setting the idInterval and invoking the moveSectionSown callback

Comment: You should provide the code you are using

Comment: Here's what I've got so far:

Comment: (function($) {
  $(document).ready( function() {
  var slideTimeout;
  var idInterval;
   $('#cover-slider').fullpage({
    anchors: <?php echo json_encode($anchor); ?>,
    navigation: true,
    continuousVertical: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    animateAnchor: false,
    scrollingSpeed: 900,
    afterRender: function() {
    idInterval = setInterval(function(){
         
                       $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
 
                 }, 4500);

    
    

      }
    }

   }); //coverslider


  }); //doc ready
 })(jQuery); 
</script>

Comment: @BenTong update the question. Its impossible to read the code in the comment. And ideally create a jsfiddle reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AJAX to load the pages when clicking on the menu, and it seems you are not clearing the interval.

Whenever you click on the menu you have to clear your interval, something like:

```
//having this interval
var myInterval  = setInterval({
    //do whatever
}, 1500);


//on click on your menu links
$('#myMenu').click(function(){
    //do whatever

    //clear interval
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```